# Pass function as parameter using tidy_eval/rlang context

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

I have a function that I want to pass a function to. However, I can't seem to get it to work using the tidy_eval context.

Here is some data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~A, ~B,
  "hi", "hello",
  "bye", "later"
)
```

I want to be able to call the function like so:

```
my_quoting_fn(df, A, str_detect(., pattern = "h*"))
```

where the third parameter can be any different function.

Here is my first attempt to write the function:

```
my_quoting_fn <- function(df, col, func) {
  func <- enquo(func)
  expr <- quo_get_expr(func)

  df %>% 
    pull({{col}}) %>%
    eval(expr)
```

The above gives the error:

> Error in eval(., expr) : invalid 'envir' argument of type 'language'`

If I try:

```
my_quoting_fn <- function(df, col, func) {

  df %>% 
    pull({{col}}) %>%
    {{func}}
```

I get the error

> Error in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
>     object '.' not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass your function as a formula with a tilde (`~`) you could use `rlang::as_function()`.

```
my_quoting_fn <- function(df, col, func) {
    func = as_function(func)

    df %>%
        pull({{col}}) %>%
        func
}
my_quoting_fn(df, A, ~str_detect(., pattern = "h*"))
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: I strongly recommend this solution. It is tempting to create new syntax with metaprogramming, but this is rarely the correct approach because it ends up confusing users.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful suggestion- that worked perfectly. As a follow-up, say I want to give input to the function within the function- i.e., tell it which column to run `str_detect` on, do you know how I could go about that? E.g., `func(A)`

Comment: @JesseKerr I don't know of the top off my head and I don't have time to look into it right now. :)  Maybe ask a new question?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to tilde-quote, you'll need to quote the expression and parse it into a form `rlang::as_function` understands before converting it so it can be called:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
    ~A, ~B,
    "hi", "hello",
    "bye", "later"
)

my_quoting_fn <- function(df, col, func) {
    func <- enexpr(func) %>%    # only want the expression, not the environment of a quosure
        rlang::new_formula(NULL, .) %>%    # tilde-quote the expression
        rlang::as_function()    # make it a formula

    df %>% 
        pull({{col}}) %>% 
        func()
}

my_quoting_fn(df, A, str_detect(., pattern = "h*"))
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
```

This isn't a well-known idiom, though; keeping it simple is probably better.